# How to freeze time for a test?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm using `time` crate and I want to test the output of my function which is associated with the time.

I want to `freeze` the time by given time; how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean you have a function like:

```
pub fn is_now_afternoon() -> bool {
    let t = time::now();
    t.tm_hour >= 12
}
```

And you want to test whether it works with particular times.

I would structure it slightly differently and pass the time in:

```
// More generic helper function, which does all the real work
fn is_t_afternoon(t: &Tm) -> bool {
    t.tm_hour >= 12
}

// Simple wrapper to use now.
pub fn is_now_afternoon() -> bool {
    is_t_afternoon(&time::now())
}

#[test]
fn test_afternoon() {
    assert!(is_t_afternoon(Tm{ tm_hour: 13, /* other fields */ }));
    assert!(!is_t_afternoon(Tm{ tm_hour: 10, /* other fields */ }));
}
```

The idea being that you separate out the code that does all the work into separate, more easily testable functions which don't depend on the "real world" environment.  As a bonus, I often find those more generic functions useful later in other contexts.

The other strategy (which I think is harder and more error prone) is to calculate independently what the answer is given the current time in the test function, and check that the real one agrees.  However this seems likely to lead to intermittent tests, or just having the same bug in the test as the "real" function.

Comment: How did you make these assumptions?

Comment: I just meant that's what I think is being asked.

Comment: Additionally, asking multiple times what the `now()` is can quickly lead to a disaster. Imagine processing starting at 11:59:59 (no afternoon) and ending at 12:00:01 (afternoon), the transition in the middle of the processing can quickly lead to inconsistent output; it's often best to capture the starting time and base every functional decision on this one snapshot.